# What is the meaning of 'que' in math?

Tags: definition

As part of a lengthy mathematical proof on density functions, part of the text says:

> We know that given $\{x_n\}_{n\in N} \subset R $ such that *que* $  x_n\to z\in R^c$  , we have that the corresponding times $t(x_n)\to +\infty$, so $h_1(x_n)\to \infty$: This means that if we make $\rho(y)| \frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x} (h_1^{-1}(y))|\to 0 $ as $y\to \infty$ we will achieve continuity of $\bar\rho$ in $R^c$.

Forgettin about details, what is the meaning of que?

Comment: Looks like either a typo, or something the author forgot to define, or something the author defined but you missed it.

Comment: I think there is no special meaning, there must be some mistake.

Comment: Perhaps a leftover of a translation from Frensh or Spanish?

Comment: Good idea @martini, that is very likely.

Comment: It is clearly a leftover (my bet would be French). "Such that" can be written in that context "tel que" in French. That plus the strange syntax indicating a foreigner (I am French...).

Comment: In spanish, we say "tal que" instead of "such that". It could be that, too.

Comment: It seems to be Spanish, though ... Google gives [this](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAAahUKEwiJlJy9ivnHAhXJ8XIKHXEFARk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fing.edu.uy%2Fiie%2Fpublicaciones%2F2006%2FMon06a%2FMon06a.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG4Jg_7wAiWwk0CGzZm0_0Ykkp7Jw&sig2=fCFB2qrv-wi6Sh9ZunLtAA) as a possible source.

Comment: In Portuguese they also say "tal que".

Comment: That's it. @martini! The document I'm working on is part of the same source you gave :)

Comment: Then forget the "que" @JasonStack, is has no (mathematical) meaning here (besides indicating that the text was Spanish sometimes ;-)).

Comment: Lol! Ok thanks @martini :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm in Paris. Why?